# Find equation of a plane throw two given point and orthogonal to another space

Tags: geometry

I have $\pi:4y-3z-4=0 \quad A=(2,4,4) \quad B=(2,-2,-4)$.
I have to calculate the equation of the plane $\sigma$ throw $A$ and $B$ and orthogonal to $\pi$.
What is the solution?
Thanks in advice!

Comment: the answer is $x-2=0$ but I can't explain why.

Answer (score 0):

HINT

I would say:

$\pi:0x+4y-3z-4=0 \quad A=(2,4,4) \quad B=(2,-2,-4)$

Search plane direction vectors: $\vec{u}=\vec{AB}=(0,-6-8), \quad \vec{v}=(0,4,-3)$

$\Rightarrow$ parametric equation of plane: $x=2+0s+0t, y = 4-6s+4t, z = 4-8s-3t;\,s,t\in R$

$\Rightarrow$ general equation of the plane: x = 2

Comment: woo!! just a question, how did you get $\overrightarrow{u}$? It seems you did the sum of $-A+B$

Comment: @HakoonaMatata Yes, $\vec{u}=\vec{AB}=(2,-2,-4)-(2,4,4)=(0,-6,-8)$.

Answer (score 0):

i am going to give it a try.  i am going to assume that a plane $\alpha$ orthogonal to $4y-3z - 4 = 0$ through the origin means there is a line in $\alpha$ that is parallel to the normal $(0,4, -3)^T$ of $\pi$  suppose $\alpha$ is given by $ax + by + cz = 0$ normality condition gives you $4b - 3c= 0.$ pick $c = 4t, b = 3t, t$ arbitray.

so $\alpha$ is given by $ax +3ty + 4tz = 0$ even though it looks like we have two degrees of freedom, in truth it has only one because only the ratio counts. let the required plane parallel to $\alpha$ be given  by  $$ax +3ty + 4tz = k$$  making the points $A = (2, 4, 4), B(2, -2, -4)$ on it requires $2a + 12t + 16t = d, 2a-6t - 16t = d$ that gives $$ t = 0, d = 2a$$

so the required plane is $$x = 2$$ as you conjectured.