# plane throw two points and paralell to another plane

Tags: geometry

I have $\pi:4y−3z−4=0 \quad A=(2,4,4) \quad B=(2,−2,−4)$. I have to calculate the equation of the plane σ throw A and B and **parallel** (*not orthogonal*)  to π. What is the solution? Thanks in advice!
And if I have three points, what's the solution?

Comment: I think this is a duplicate

Comment: it is. here is the link http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1110831  asked by the same person and with two answers to boot.

Comment: it's not a duplicate! it's similar... now I want to know the parallel plane, not the orthogonal.

Answer (score 1):

The (unique!) plane through $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ parallel to $ax + by + cz = d$ is given by
$$
a(x-x_0)+b(y-y_0)+c(z-z_0)=0
$$
The other point is unnecessary information.